# Matrix related question

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

[image: in this a picture a matrix is given which is solved]

My question is why new equation is named as 3rd equation after adding equation first and third. Why don't we name it as first equation and then write in the place of first equation in the new matrix.

Answer (score 1):

The three elementary operations are:

- Swap two equations
- Multiply an equation by a non-zero number
- Add a multiple of one equation to another

In you're example they are using the third operation, they are adding $4$ times the first equation to the third equation.  This operation always changes the third equation (you're adding a multiple of one equation **to** another).

If you were to replace equation $1$ with this new equation you would be doing two operations, first multiply equation $1$ by $4$, then add $1$ times the third equation to the first equation.

The point of sticking to just these three equations is to make the steps in the process as simple, as easy to follow, and as easy to analyze as possible.

Comment: **not satisfied**

Comment: Well if you don't explain why your not satisfied then there's nothing anyone can do about it is there?